# input/output error with external hard drive

Tags: bash, usb

I have a problem with my backup external drive.
Can you help please ?

**EDIT** I ran chkdsk from a windows machine. There messages with sectors issues. Now I still have the display below with "?" when I list the directories from my linux machine. Is it possible to retrieve what's in BackupsmonPC ??

```
ro:LACIEBIG$ ll
ls: cannot access '.Trashes': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'BackupsmonPC': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'Results': Input/output error
total 42M
d????????? ? ?       ?          ?              ? BackupsmonPC
-rwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro  16K mars   8  2013 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro 4,0K nov.  23  2019 MarieCas
drwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro 4,0K juin  27  2008 photos Digues StJean
drwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro  42M févr. 19  2013 recupSite
d????????? ? ?       ?          ?              ? Results
-rwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro   36 mars   8  2013 syncguid.dat
drwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro 4,0K févr.  4  2009 System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro    0 juin  24  2014 .Trash-1000
d????????? ? ?       ?          ?              ? .Trashes
-rwxrwxrwx 1 louisro louisro 4,0K mars   8  2013 ._.Trashes
```

The drive is in NTFS format.

Ntfsfix doens't see the drive:

```
ro$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd
Failed to determine whether /dev/sdd is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access '/dev/sdd': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdd': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access '/dev/sdd': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdd': No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Failed to access '/dev/sdd': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdd': No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

**EDIT**
I ran this test:

```
ro:LACIEBIG$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb -d sat
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-193-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SAMSUNG SpinPoint T166
Device Model:     SAMSUNG HD501LJ
Serial Number:    S0MUJ13P709421
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0000f0 01b709421
Firmware Version: CR100-10
User Capacity:    500 107 862 016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.5, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Wed Nov 18 20:10:16 2020 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 8924) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 152) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   253   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   015    Pre-fail  Always       -       7104
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       292
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   253   253   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   253   253   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   253   253   015    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       634
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   253   253   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0012   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       272
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   078   052   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   172   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       40956
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Total_Pending_Sectors   0x0012   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x000a   253   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
201 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    0x000a   253   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Data_Address_Mark_Errs  0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

and also this test:

```
$ sudo e2fsck -c /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you point to how to run a SMART test ?

Comment: I just ran a smart test. What do you think?

Comment: Looks to me like your drive is old, and currently corrupted beyond ntfsfix's ability to repair. Next step: Use a Windows system to run chkdisk. Since you say this is a backup disk, you can run it until complete failure. Have a plan in mind to replace the hardware if chkdisk cannot restore the filesystem, of if the same corruption happens again tomorrow.

Comment: I ran chkdsk, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. `fsck` gave a clean system in my case on `/dev/sde`. It took me some time to notice that the file check needs to be done on the partition; and, using e2fsck is the better option. So

```
e2fsck -p /dev/sde1
```

I once did this without the `-p` and/or maybe that was not on the partition or on the drive - can't remember but after running `e2fsck` it would run with a report saying the drive had errors but closed without a warning. The `-p` on the partition removed the superblock warning.

Then I did 2 things of which I don't know which helped:

1. I did a reboot without the drive connected and
2. then reconnected the drive.

All in all, the `e2fsck` plus the `-p` plus the reboot plus the reconnect or one or some combination of them fixed the problem.